# How to test tensorflow model on unseen data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I have trained a CNN model using TF, and now I want to test(evaluate) it on unseen data. How can i do this ?

Comment: Is this a question about how to use Tensorflow? If not, could you clarify what the actual question is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build the model (including training and testing), you can hold out some data for some final "unseen data test".

In other words, suppose you have 10K data, you can have 4K training, 4K testing, and final 2K for "unseen data test".

Note that, many terms exists and confusing. Such as "validation data set" or "test set", it can mean different things. You may further to research and get details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Problem is my model is giving me really high accuracy in a small number of iterations which doesn't seem right. So i wanted to somehow provide unseen data, to model and observe its actual perfomence.

Comment: Do you think, save/restore could work? as far as data is concerned i have seprated CSV files of newly recorded data which model has never seen, so splitting is not really an issue

Comment: @SalmanShaukat many people build model with "fixed amount" of data. That is why those terms exist. If you have real "newly collected / unseen" data, that is even better.